# Cache REST Response

Tags: 8, caching

Is it possible to cache the rest response other than CORS? Or is it possible to cache the response using memcache? Or is there a method available on rest for the caching?

Update to include a sample response created:-

```
class SampleResource extends ResourceBase {
  public function get($node) {
    $data = [
      'title' => $node->title(),
      'sample_field' => $node->sample_field
    ];

    $response = new ResourceResponse($data);
    $response->addCacheableDependency($node);
    $response->addCacheableDependency(CacheableMetadata::createFromRenderArray([
      '#cache' => ['tags' => ['rebuild_response_' . $node->id()]],
    ]));

    return $response;
  }
}
```

Comment: do you want add cache to response ?

Comment: The Dynamic Page Cache module can cache any response object that implements CacheableResponseInterface, if this is a custom controller/API then make sure you return such an object. Share your code when in doubt

Comment: Yes, and the Internal Page Cache (for anonymous traffic) caches all responses, with or without implementing the CacheableResponseInterface.

Comment: hi @bedir, I'm new to d8 and I'm not familiar yet with core modules. I've updated my post and include what I've done so far. Could you please create a sample response using CacheableResponseInterface?

Comment: @4k4 how to test if the response has been cached?

Comment: @CatherineSalvador, look for the response headers `X-Drupal-Cache` and `X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache`.